# how to use .C files in Scala project

Tags: c++, scala

I had a library implementation in C
In C/C++ I use include the library that map to the implementation file to use those API
How I do that in Scala with that .C file ?
I mean is there any way to use it like import the file or some thing ?
the source code in C is very long to convert to scala

Comment: You'll have to use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Comment: Or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_to_Java_Virtual_Machine_compilers#C_to_bytecode_compilers . I am not sure I'd recommend that route, though.

Answer (score 0):

As vanza said you can use JNI. However you can also use JNA (https://github.com/twall/jna#readme) which is much simpler as you don't need any C-side wrapper. Both of these requires dynamically compiled libraries.